# pytest and Tavern

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm using tavern and pytest to perform a simple post request and check the response from a mock api endpoint. I'm doing it in the below fashion using a yaml file. Pytest works using the basic post yaml minus the items ($ext:, function: utils:post_function, and extra_kwargs:). We have a need to use the same yaml file but with an external function so to pass the response variables to another yaml file to be used in a get request. How can a yaml file in this fashion using pytest call external functions?

```
pytest.exe post.tavern.yaml --junit-xml=./pass.xml
```

post.tavern.yaml

```
stages:
 -name: Make sure number is returned correctly
  request:
    url: path_to_my_mock_endpoint
    method: POST
    headers:
      content-type: application/json
  response:
    status_code: 202
    body:
      $ext:
        function: utils:post_function
        extra_kwargs:
          responseText: "Great job!"
          responseCode: 202
          tavernVerification: 1001
```

utils.py

```
def post_function(response,**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

Comment: Please edit your code sample using a four spaces indent before it so we can get the indentation right (kind of important in yaml & python :) )

Comment: This question was also raised on the Tavern issues: https://github.com/taverntesting/tavern/issues/71

Comment: One way to achieve this, assuming you're trying to run tests out of the same project is this:
    \---Tests
        \---YamlFiles
        |   |   test_foo.tavern.yaml
        |   |   test_bar.tavern.yaml
        |   |   
        \---src
            |   util.py:my_func
            |
    in test_foo.tavern.yaml:

$ext: # This is a relative path to your python code function: Tests.YamlFiles.util:my_func